# Visual Studio 2015 requires admin rights

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

My app needs to run as an administrator account and so in the `app.manifest` I have the following:

```xml
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

If I run Visual Studio 2013 without admin rights in Release x86 it doesn't ask me to restart with admin rights.

However, running the same app in Visual Studio 2015 without admin rights in Release x86 I get prompted with the following dialog when trying to run the app:

[image: Dialog]

Is this a bug in 2013 that was fixed for 2015? Or is it unexpected behaviour in 2015?

I assume it is a fix in 2015 as that seems like the correct behaviour, but why was this changed?

Comment: I believe prompting is the correct behavior. Well, if you ask for a bug report number, you can only contact Microsoft support team.

Comment: @LexLi It probably is the correct behaviour. However, it is different from 2013 and I would like to know which is correct from official sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug in VS2013.  The problem is that your program is running with the wrong manifest.  It uses the manifest that is embedded in the yourapp.vshost.exe file, it doesn't match the manifest you created.  The bug was indeed fixed in VS2015.  There are several bug reports about it, [this one](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/805985/vs-does-not-suggest-to-launch-elevated-when-the-developed-application-require-elevation) is probably best.  Big blunder, an agile problem, and not addressed in the updates.

It has a simple workaround, beyond elevating VS up front, use Project > Properties > Debugging and untick the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" checkbox.  Now the manifest embedded in your EXE is active and VS knows to prompt you to elevate.  This setting is not critical unless you have a very unusual setup, like building to an untrusted network share.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample .Net WinForms application in my VS2013 and I get exactly the same prompt. I believe you actually have your VS2013 run as administrator without noticing it, usually via compatibility settings on `devenv.exe`.

The other problem could be your EXE that is compiled wrong for whatever reason. In the prompt, click "details" and carefully navigate exactly to the path specified (it can actually be different from what you expect), then run application from disk. Does Windows prompt for UAC / credentials?